# How to save selected item in combobox and long number from textbox in sql statement?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, combobox, textbox

I don't know how to save the selected item from combobox and long number from textbox. Here's my code:

```
string num = txtNum.Text;
string q = "insert into new (name, group, phoneNum) values('" + name + "', '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "', "+ num +")";
```

`bombobox1` contains these item:

```
"group A"
"group B"
"group C"
```

When I choose 1 of the items, it must be saved in the database (MS Access), and `txtNum.text` must have 11 numbers like 09999999999 and save it to MS Access. When I click the button, the value of combobox and textbox must be saved. (I may have an error with SQL statement and string formatting).

Comment: What is yur current result? Do you get any errors? We can only help you if you try to add a little bit more info. See [ask] if you need help on that.

Comment: it has an error like "syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"

Answer (score 0):

GROUP is a reserved keyword in MS Access, you need to encapsulate it in square brakets when used in sql queries

```
string q = "insert into new (name, [group], phoneNum) values(.......
```

Said that, it is important that you change your sql command string and the following database code to make use of parameterized query. It is of uttermost importance to avoid parsing problems with strings, numbers and dates, but also to avoid the Sql Injection vulnerability problem.

```
string q = "insert into new (name, [group], phoneNum) values(?,?,?)";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", name);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", Convert.ToInt64(num));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If the field PhoneNum is a simple char field type then you pass the third parameter without conversion

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", num);
```

Comment: the "name" is used for string value like this

(string name = txtAdd.Text + " " + txtAdd2.Text + "."+" " + txtAdd3.Text;)

Comment: sorry, GROUP not NAME

Comment: Also I suggest to change the datatype for the phoneNum to a string. Usually there is no need to use a Long numeric on phone numbers (and in certain countries the phone number could contain letters)

Comment: Has I have said, I think you should change the field in the database to be a text instead of a number. There is no need to treat a PhoneNumber as a number. Think about a number like (0012)1223-2234. If you want to store it as is you need a text field. Of course this means that you pass a string as a parameter to the INSERT statement

Comment: the data type i used for group and phoneNum is only short text, is that right?

Comment: Fields are of type CHAR(size) or TEXT (also know as Memo) there is no Short Text as far as I know. However, it seems correct, but in this case you pass a string parameter for the phoneNum field (Updating answer)

Comment: what should i put in values(?,?,?) ? the "@p1"?

Comment: No, you put exactly the char ?. This is the parameter placeholder required by OleDb. It will bu substituted by the actual parameter value in the corresponding position. So the value for parameter @p1 (a name as another name it doesn't matter with oledb) will be placed in the position of the first ? with the correct quoting required by the underlying parameter type

Comment: By the way, I have just noticed that you name your table `new`. Is that correct?